# Can I read one pdf document on two ipads each showing a facing page?

Tags: software-recommendation, display, pdf, software, adobe

I would like to be able to read a 60 page pdf on 2 ipads that will display facing pages.  (one page per ipad)  Pages should turn like a book as if both ipads are the facing pages of a book.